# Change event is not getting triggering when pre-select the selected date again in kendo ui calendar

Tags: kendo-ui

Change event is not triggering when i select the already selected date.

Example: in calendar the selected date is 03-Dec-2013 and if i select the same date again 
the change event is not triggering.

Comment: Well, the event is called "change", not "click", so this is the expected behavior. What do you want to do when the same date is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bind to the click event of the selected date cell.

E.g.
$("#calendar").on("click", "td.k-state-selected", function (e) {

});

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. The `change` event is fired only when the value of the widget changes.

Answer (score 0):

try to attach a event to the click event of the calendar like so each time it will triguger

```
$(document).ready(funciton(){
$(document).on('click', '#calendar', function (evt) {
    alert($(this).val());
});
});
```